# why credentials are not shown in mitmproxy?

Tags: tls, android

my question is that why I can not see some credentials in mitmproxy while the application connecting to, uses ssl connection? I actually installed the mitmproxy server on my PC and have set up my android smartphone to connect to that proxy before connecting to the main server. I have not installed the proxy certificate in my smartphone so that to find insecure apps. some apps easily accept the mitmproxy certificate and establish ssl connections. I know that mitmproxy works based on SSL so my expectation is to see the credentials (like username and password ) that I already entered in app while connecting to the proxy. however, I sometimes see them in the proxy and sometimes I do not even after the app successfully connects to the proxy. now I wonder why I can not see the credentials entered in some apps in the proxy?my assume was that maybe those android apps do not use SSL encryption method and use other protocols for encryption so that is the reason I do not see the credentials in the proxy; though after using wireshark, I found out that all of those apps were using ssl protocol. do any one can help me to figure out why those credentials are not shown in the proxy? maybe I think in the wrong way so any answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't see the credentials because the application **required** to have a valid certificate. If **the certificate is not valid**, then the application won't process the HTTPS connection.

If you use mitmproxy to perform MiTM attack, that means the application uses the mitmproxy certificate.

Maybe you can try the application to process the **untrusted** connection.